# How do i create ActionLink for Partial view in Asp.net MVC with out controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have Select box and when user select item of Select box it fires Partial View Dynamically.
 My Plan is create ActionLinks inside each option items. I already created my partial views. I don't have plan to create separate controller actions for that partial views.I want to call partial views when user select option items like
 @Html.ActionLink("Link for my Partial View") 
 method or something like this. 
How i do this with Razor? Are there any another ways to do this?
  
edit:There are 12 partial views available to render, so Is there any way to run code without Action and I want to fire the partial view without click submit button?

Answer (score 1):

you can change using jquery like that.

```
@Html.DropDownList("DropDownCategory", new SelectList(Model.Category, "ID", "Name"))
@Html.ActionLink("Submit name", "ActionName", "ControllerName", null, new { @id = "SubmitName" })

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#SubmitName').click(function () {
        var value = $('#DropDownCategory').val();
        var path = '@Url.Content("~/ControllerName/ActionName")' + "?CategoryId=" + value
        $(this).attr("href", path);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try
- first need to get selected value changed of select box and then call action from your controller

On Controller (HomeController)

```
 public PartialViewResult PartialViewTest()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
```

On View

```
<select>
<option value="0">One</option>
<option value="1">Two</option>
```

```
<script>
$("select").change(function () {
    $.get('@Url.Action("PartialViewTest", "Home")', function (data) {
        $('#detailsDiv').replaceWith(data);
    });
}).trigger('change');
```

Hoping it can help you